# How can I use Microsoft login for my APEX app?

Tags: openid

I have tried following https://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2018/02/apex-authentication-with-microsoft-account.html to enable logging into an APEX app using the MS login credentials. Having followed these instructions, the MS login screen appears when I navigate to the APEX app home page; however I get the following error message from MS:

> We're unable to complete your request invalid_request: The provided
>   value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The
>   expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for
>   this client application.

The redirect URI I have used is https://apexea.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_authentication.callback as per the blog.

One thing done differently from the blog is the registering of the app on Azure rather than through https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ as this service is no longer supported. The home page URL defined in Azure would not accept a link directly to the home page (i.e. [https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=[app #]:[page # of home page]](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=[app%20#]:[page%20#%20of%20home%20page]) is not accepted:  but: [https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=[app #]](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=[app%20#]) is accepted)

Any help resolving would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to answer my own question.

The correct APEX redirect URI for newer versions of APEX is:

https://apexea.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_authentication.callback

Thanks to the update on https://fuzziebrain.com/content/id/1709/ that stated

> UPDATE [May 4, 2018]
>   apex.oracle.com was upgraded to APEX 18.1 (previously known as 5.2) last month. The instructions provided in this blog post is still relevant. Simply replace any links or references using apexea to apex.